# LibreOffice with a docx file with bibliography

Tags: linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, bibliography, endnote

A colleague has sent me a `docx` file containing a text and a bibliography, the text has references to the bibliography appearing as `[1]` on a gray background. However, these references appear to be treated as plain text by LibreOffice with my linux box.

I presume the bibliography is handled by EndNote on my colleague's apple computer. The only relevant link I've found makes [a suggestion](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-General/LibreOffice-Writer-Endnote-citations-and-bibliography-are/td-p/132980) but there is no reply whether this worked for anyone.

I'm looking for some way to generate/convert the document that I can suggest to my colleague so that (1) the cross-references are not lost for *him* if I edit the text and send back the document without editing bibliography, or even better (2) I can access the bibliography.

Comment: A search for "endnote libreoffice" brings up a number of links about using an extension, for example [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3857/can-i-use-writer-with-endnote-software/).

Comment: Thx. I'll search again--the link you give is for windows and running endnote, I've now edited to mention I'm using linux and not running endnote.

Comment: @JimK: it doesn't seem there's any answer to the question I'm asking with the keywords you suggest.

Comment: Probably not; I originally thought you had EndNote installed and were using Windows.  Any chance you could ask your colleague to switch to something like Zotero instead, which [works on Linux](https://www.zotero.org/support/installation)?